# Null Reference Problem In Inherited Object

Tags: c#, inheritance, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to code simple membership class. First class name is Customer and it has others classes like Silver_Customer, Gold_Customer which are inherited from Customer class.

I use these classes in my simple windows application:

```
    public Customer customer;
    public Form_MURAT_TURAN()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product p1 = new Product("Blouse", 152.80);
        Product p2 = new Product("T-Shirt", 50.25);
        .....
        lbProducts.Items.Add(p1);
        lbProducts.Items.Add(p2);
        .....
    }

    private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Customer customer = new Standard_Customer(txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, 0);
        customer.Name = "Mark 1";
        customer.TotalAmount = 5;
        gbCustomer.Enabled = false;
        gbProduct.Enabled = true;

        set_info(customer.customerType(), customer.Name + " " + customer.Surname, customer.TotalAmount);
    }

    private void btnAddToBasket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customer.Name = "Mark 2";
    }
```

Everything works fine except btnAddToBasket_Click method. customer.Name = "Mark 2"; line give me `NullReferenceException` error but customer.Name = "Mark 1" line works.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your Customer, Standard_Customer classes?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `btnCustomer_Click`, you are not setting your global `customer` object. You are setting a local version of it. Change your code as follows:

```
private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customer = new Standard_Customer(txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, 0);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain the null reference exception he is seeing.

Comment: @tomf: yes, it does. The `customer` object was never set, because a totally different object named `customer` was set instead.

Comment: You're right, I wrongly thought the exception was occurring in btnCustomer_Click.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try:

```
private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.customer = new Standard_Customer(txtName.Text, txtSurname.Text, 0);
        customer.Name = "Mark 1";
        customer.TotalAmount = 5;
        gbCustomer.Enabled = false;
        gbProduct.Enabled = true;

        set_info(customer.customerType(), customer.Name + " " + customer.Surname, customer.TotalAmount);
    }
```

Try using `this.customer` when you create a new customer.